# How to show values of referenced tables in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to rails and have made a basic app with two tables but I have not figured out how to show the value of the referenced table instead of the id.
My two tables are `Genres` and `Songs` and look like this.

```
id | trackgenre  |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+-------------+----------------------------+-------------------------

  1 | Classic | 2017-06-13 02:37:07.041974 | 2017-06-13 02:37:07.041974

  2 | Rock     | 2017-06-13 02:37:07.060634 | 2017-06-13 02:37:07.060634

  3 | Hip-Hop   | 2017-06-13 02:37:07.064877 | 2017-06-13 02:37:07.064877

  4 | Alternative     | 2017-06-13 02:37:07.067473 | 2017-06-13 02:37:07.067473





  id | songtitle  |         artist        |         genre_id         
----+-------------+----------------------------+---------------------------

  1 | Loser         | Beck                  | 4

  2 | Jailhouse rock | Elvis Presley        | 2

  3 | My Way        | Frank Sinatra         | 2
```

My `song.rb` looks like this

```
class Song < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :genre
end
```

and `genre.rb` is

```
class Genre < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :songs
end
```

Now when I am fetching data from the front end, I see the `genre_id` instead of the value. For example, if i fetch the second item from my Songs table, I get Jailhouse rock, Elvis Presley, 2. What would I have to do to get the value of genre_id that is "Rock" to show up on the front end instead of this number 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fetching the second item from Songs simply by

```
Song.second
```

This would give you `genre_id` which is in the `Songs` table. If you want name of the genre or in this case `trackgenre, you'll have to join the tables:

```
Song.joins(:genre).select("songs.*", "genres.trackgenre").second
```

This would give you all attributes of Song and Genre Name, which means `genre_id` and `trackgenre`. If do not want `genre_id` and just `trackgenre`, you will have to select attributes of the song.

```
Song.joins(:genre).select("songs.id", "songs.songtitle", "songs.artist", "genres.trackgenre").second
```

Comment: Awesome. But I always thought joins were done through associations when I did these in the models files... belongs_to :genre has_many :songs. Aren't these joining tables? Sorry if i sound like a total noob. I just assume that rails does everything for me sometimes. And where would I actually do the join if i wanted to do it for all the songs in my database?

Comment: The belongs_to and has_many are associations which basically define methods that you can use to extract attributes from more than one associated tables. Rails doesn't join tables for you until you use `joins` method. After you specify associations, Rails allows you to join tables using `joins` or `includes`. 
To extract attributes from both `Song` and `Genre`, you will have to join them. 
To extract all songs with genre name, use the query above and replace `second` by `all`. `second` gives you the second song, `all` gives you all the songs.

Answer (score 2):

> I have not figured out how to show the value of the referenced table
>   instead of the id

You just need to do

```
<%= @song.genre.trackgenre %>
```

Where `@song` is an instance of `Song`